# How to validate Size and color in Product details page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

On click of "Click here and check" which is in the image.
validate Size and color. If not select show validation message like [required this field.]

[image]

please find .phtml file

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg action towishlist" 
id="popupButton" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" >
<span>Click here and check</span> 
</a>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" 
style="display:none;">
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title"><?php echo $this->helper('Magedelight\PriceDropAlert\Helper\Data')->getConfig('Magedelight_PriceDropAlert/price_drop_popup_configuration/price_drop_popup_title'); ?></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <form method="post" action="pricedropalert/index/submit">
          <input type="hidden" name="email" id="user_email" 
          value="<?php echo $block->getUserEmail(); ?>">
          <input type="hidden" name="product_id" id="proId" value="<?php echo $block->getCurrentProduct(); ?>">
          <input type="hidden" name="sku" value="<?php echo $block->getCurrentProductSku(); ?>">
          <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="<?php echo $block->getUserId(); ?>">
          <input type="hidden" name="CurrentPrice" value="<?php echo $block->getCurrentProductPrice(); ?>">
        <?php if($this->helper('Magedelight\PriceDropAlert\Helper\Data')->getConfig('Magedelight_PriceDropAlert/general/desired_price')):?>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="number" id="desired_price" placeholder="<?php echo $this->helper('Magedelight\PriceDropAlert\Helper\Data')->getConfig('Magedelight_PriceDropAlert/price_drop_popup_configuration/price_textbox_placeholder'); ?>" name="desired_price" class="input-text required-entry form-control" data-validate="{required:true}" autocomplete="off" aria-required="true" required>
          </div><br>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="cookies_email" placeholder="<?php echo $this->helper('Magedelight\PriceDropAlert\Helper\Data')->getConfig('Magedelight_PriceDropAlert/price_drop_popup_configuration/alert_email_placeholder'); ?>" name="email" required>
        </div><br>
          <?php if($this->helper('Magedelight\PriceDropAlert\Helper\Data')->getConfig('Magedelight_PriceDropAlert/gdpr_consent/consent_checkbox')): ?>
          <div class="checkbox">
              <label><input type="checkbox" name="gdpr_consent" value="1" required> 
              <?php echo $this->helper('Magedelight\PriceDropAlert\Helper\Data')->getConfig('Magedelight_PriceDropAlert/gdpr_consent/gdpr_consent'); ?>
              </label>
          </div><br>
          <?php endif; ?>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><?php echo $this->helper('Magedelight\PriceDropAlert\Helper\Data')->getConfig('Magedelight_PriceDropAlert/price_drop_popup_configuration/drop_alert_button'); ?></button>
      </form>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>  

 <script>
 require(
  [
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
  ],
  function(
    $,
    modal
  ) {
    var options = {
        type: 'popup',
        responsive: true,
        innerScroll: true,
        buttons: [{
            text: $.mage.__('Cancel'),
            class: 'mymodal1',
            click: function () {
                this.closeModal();
            }
        }]
    };
    var popup = modal(options, $('#myModal'));
    $("#popupButton").on('click',function(){
        $("#myModal").modal("openModal");
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: plese share phtml file where you added "Click here and check" link

Comment: please add path of phtml. share the whole process, how you get the button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#popupButton").on('click',function(){ //Model id
    var form = $("#product_addtocart_form");
    var i = 0;
    form.find('input').each(function () {
       if($(this).attr('aria-required'))
           if(!$(this).val())
               i++;
    });
    if (!i) { //size or color is not selected yet
        $("#mymodal").modal("openModal");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can use "mage/mage" js like this

`require(['jquery', "mage/mage"], function($){`

`var dataForm = $('#form_id'); // you can find form id in <form> tag`

`dataForm.mage('validation', {ignore: ':hidden'}); // This will ignore Display none field to validate`

`if(dataForm.validation('isValid')){`

`// Open your popup`

`}`

`});`